# how can I change the default months in my en.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I already change some default errors messages, but the last thing I need is change the default month names, I tried:

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
   activerecord:
    errors:
     messages:
      taken: "este mail ya sido utilizado"
        confirmation: "password y confirmacion no coinciden"

    date:
       month_names: "enero"
```

but doesn`t work, please help, 
thanks in advance.

Comment: You have not yet accepted answers to any of your other questions.  You should do so.  This link may help explain how accepting questions works http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

From the [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#overview-of-other-built-in-methods-that-provide-i18n-support) I posted in your other question, you can find the [file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml#L15) that defines the english month names.

month_names is an array, not a string, so you need to specify all 12 (and a nil as the first value.)

You have also nested `date:` to deep.  It needs to be nested directly below `en:`

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
    # Don't forget the nil at the beginning; there's no such thing as a 0th month
    month_names: [~, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December]
```

Comment: **RESOLVED**  in my config/locales/en.yml I added:                                    en:
  hello: "Hello world"
  
  date:
    formats:
      
      # When no format has been given, it uses default.
      # You can provide other formats here if you like!
      default: "%Y-%m-%d"
      short: "%b %d"
      long: "%B %d, %Y"

    day_names: [Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday]
    , Sat]
     month_names: [~, Enero, Febrero, Marzo, Abril, Mayo, Junio, Julio, Agosto, Septiembre, Octubre, Noviembre, Diciembre]